# Memgraph 2.5.0 does not return qid in the Success message metadata

Tags: memgraphdb

In Memgraph v2.5.0, when I execute a query within the explicit transaction Memgraph does not return qid in the Success message metadata. Therefore, I cannot use correlated pulls. What to use instead? The server should assign qid to a query within an explicit transaction and return it in the metadata of the Success packet.

Comment: According to https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/718.  This should be working as of January 2022.  Check you are up-to-date. If you are, then we can look for a workaround. As far as I can see, the latest version is 2.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @drJay has said in the comment this was a bug that was fixed. Migrating to new version has solved the issue.